# how to connect to azure (management) rest api via C# in IIS

Tags: azure, x509certificate

I am trying to setup a website (local testing atm), to connect to azure rest api to see our settings.  I created a cert locally (W7 machine):

```
makecert -sky exchange -r -n "CN=azureConnectionNew" -pe -a sha1 -len 2048 -ss My "azureConnectionNew.cer"
```

I can see the cert in the certs MMC snap in. (do not have a right click edit permissions option when I view the cert in here).

I have a class library that setups up the connection, the cert is passed in by getting the cert (via the thumb string), this works great for the console app, but when I try and do this in a web app it all goes wrong.  I get 403 errors.

I first thought that this was due to the fact that the website is running as the ApplicationPoolIdentity so doesn't have access to the cert.  So I tried passing in the cert (to the same code as the console app), by loading the actual file:

```
var path = @"C:\temp\azureconnection\azureConnectionNew.cer";
var cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import(path);
```

I still get 403 errors.

I tried exporting the cer file from MMC certificates snap in as a pfx file, (with private keys included).  I set the local IIS set to use this cert and navigated to the https version of my local site but still got 403.

I am not sure how to include / setup / reference the cert so that IIS can send a HttpWebRequest from the server side to Azure and get a valid response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to use Thumbprint of the certificate to get the certificate. Please make sure you have created the certificate correctly. Also please check you have placed the  certificate in Personal certificate section in Local Machine. You can check this using MMC snap in. please try below code..

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);  
           store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

           var certificate = store.Certificates
             .Cast<X509Certificate2>()
             .SingleOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.Thumbprint, “CertificateThumbprint”, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));  // please replace CertificateThumbprint with original Thumbprint
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right way to use the certificate - it needs to be stored in the personal/certificates store of the user running the code (you should update the App Pool identity to be a user who can login and into whose certificates you import the cert.  Here's sample code showing you how to use the service API: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureManagementAPI-609fc31a/