# 403 Error on Azure API Only After Deploying to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, azure, ssl

I think I have read every single thing on the internet about this (bold statement I know) but I can't work it out...

I have a very simple webpage that gets the status VMs on Azure, which works fine on my machine. I created a Cert on my local machine with makecert and debug runs fine.
After deploying it to another server on IIS all I get is 403 errors.

Things I tried:

1. Exporting Cert from my dev machine with private key and importing onto the test server
2. Creating new Cert with makecert (edit: recreated the cert on the server I want to deploy to) (according to this link from [MSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg551722.aspx)), upload to Azure, update code to search for new thumbprint, redeploy and admire the same error msg..
3. Both times I changed the app pool identity to a user account that is log-on-able (and reverted)
4. Tried with cert as both localmachine and current user, with user updated in the app pool

I changed my get cert code to more resemble an answer from a similar question, but finding the cert doesn't appear to be the issue.. if I remove the cert created on the server, I get a different error.

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);  
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var certificate = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().SingleOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.Thumbprint, thumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));  // please replace CertificateThumbprint with original Thumbprint

        return certificate;
```

Ref: [how to connect to azure (management) rest api via C# in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613737/how-to-connect-to-azure-management-rest-api-via-c-sharp-in-iis)

Code to create HttpClient:

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
String CertThumbprint = _certthumbprint;
X509Certificate2 managementCert = FindX509Certificate(CertThumbprint);
if (managementCert != null)
{
   handler.ClientCertificates.Add(managementCert);
   HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2014-05-01");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            return httpClient;
        }
```

Retrieve VMs Code:

```
String uri = String.Format("https://management.core.windows.net/{0}/services/hostedservices/{1}/deploymentslots/{2}", _subscriptionid, ServiceName, "Production");
            XDocument vms = new XDocument();
            vms.Add(new XElement("VirtualMachines"));
            ApplyNamespace(vms.Root, ns);

            try
            {
                HttpClient http = GetHttpClient();
                Stream responseStream = await http.GetStreamAsync(uri);

                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(responseStream);
                    var roles = xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "RoleInstance");
                    foreach (XElement r in roles)
                    {
                        XElement svcNamee1 = new XElement("ServiceName", ServiceName);
                        ApplyNamespace(svcNamee1, ns);
                        r.Add(svcNamee1);
                        vms.Root.Add(r);
                    }
                }

            }
```

This code is currently about 95% copy and paste from [here](https://github.com/mwasham/wasvcmgmntapi)

Comment: Your code is not deployed in an Azure Website. Correct? What happens when you create the cert on the test server itself?

Comment: Nope, sorry didn't include that, not deployed to Azure, just a Server 2012 machine here locally. Annnd didn't include that in point 2 I recreated that Cert on the server machine... will edit to include that

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the original 'AzurePublishSettingsFile', I deleted that from the cert store and now I get the 403 error on my dev machine also, reimported it and still get the 403 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution for me in this case was to create a new Publishsettings file via powershell and import that on the server via powershell. Then use the thumbprint from that in code. Making a cert on the server and uploading to Azure still doesn't work for whatever reason...